# Slice arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, system-calls, slice

I know there are easier ways to do this, but I must demonstrate removing the first seven lines of a system call (top -bn1) and write the results to a file using array slices. I currently am having trouble with the syntax of removing the seven lines, and I'm not sure how to write it to a file.

```
my @top_command = `top -bn1`;

@top_command = @top_command(7..@top_command); 

print @top_command, $file_name;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Array indexes are made with square brackets (`[]`), not parentheses.
2. You can get the highest index of an array called `@array` with `$#array`.
3. I can't even tell what you're trying to do in your third line, but you probably want to look up the [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) operator.

That should be enough to complete your assignment.

Comment: I was attempting to print the remaining contents of ` @top_command ` to a file on my third line of code.

Comment: @JohnnyDiamond08, what that will do is print the contents of `@top_command`, and then the name of a file, to your screen.  Look up print and open in perldoc to see how to do it. http://perldoc.perl.org/

Answer (score 3):

```
open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

print $fh @top_command[7..$#top_command];
```